# Cannot print to console in python whilst Flask is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask, printing

So I’m trying to make a task manager website in Python, that has an admin console and a front-end website. Initially, everything was working fine, until I added the code for the Flask webpage (shown in WebManager_Main.py) and then the console prints (shown in CommandLine_Output) just stopped working. Weirdly these are being run in two different threads (shown in main.py) so I have no idea how this happened!

Main.py

```
# Startup and import
# import libraries
import threading
import time
# import files
import CommandLine_Handler as clh
import DataBaseHandler_Main as DBHM
import WebManager_main as WBM
import Error_Handler as eh
import Mailbox as mb

# Startup
mb.run_Main = True
mb.run_Interface = True
mb.run_Database = True
mb.run_WebApp = True
mb.loop_Counter = 0

cmdInterface = None
dataBaseCreate = None
WebAppManager = None

# Run Loop
while mb.run_Main == True:
  if mb.run_Interface == True:
    try:
      if cmdInterface == None:
        cmdInterface = threading.Thread(target = clh.interface)
        cmdInterface.daemon = True
        cmdInterface.start()
      else:
        if not cmdInterface.is_alive():
          cmdInterface = threading.Thread(target = clh.interface)
          cmdInterface.daemon = True
          cmdInterface.start()
    except:
      eh.error("m-rl1")
      
  if mb.run_Database == True:
    try:
      if dataBaseCreate == None:
        dataBaseCreate = threading.Thread(target = DBHM.creator)
        dataBaseCreate.daemon = True
        dataBaseCreate.start()
      else:
        if not dataBaseCreate.is_alive():
          dataBaseCreate = threading.Thread(target = DBHM.creator)
          dataBaseCreate.daemon = True
          dataBaseCreate.start()
    except:
      eh.error("m-rl2")

  if mb.run_WebApp == True:
    try:
      if WebAppManager == None:
        WebAppManager = threading.Thread(target = DBHM.creator)
        WebAppManager.daemon = True
        WebAppManager.start()
      else:
        if not WebAppManager.is_alive():
          WebAppManager = threading.Thread(target = WBM)
          WebAppManager.daemon = True
          WebAppManager.start()
    except:
      eh.error("m-rl3")

        
  mb.loop_Counter += 1
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

CommandLine_Output.py

```
import os
import sys
import pwinput as pIN
import logging
def output(input):
  print(input, flush=True)
  # logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
  # logger.info(input)

def uInput(prompt):
   userInput = input(prompt)
   return userInput
def passInput(prompt):
  #userInput = pIN.pwinput(prompt=prompt, mask = '*')
  userInput = input(prompt)
  return userInput

def clear():
  os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
  #os.system("cls")
```

WebManager_Main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
#this is the library responsible for the hosting of the Web app
webApp = Flask(__name__)

@webApp.route("/")

def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "WebManager_main":
  webApp.run(port=8080, debug = True)
```

I’ve had a look around online at posts by people with sort of similar issues and suggestions they’ve been given. I’ve tried flushing the buffer, logging as well as attempting to disable the prints from Flask.
But I can’t seem to get the console prints from that thread anymore.

I'd greatly appreciate any help whatsoever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python web application has to be run independently by a piece of software that implements the WSGI protocol.

See [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/) to figure out how to start your webapp.  You cannot run it as a thread like you did in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm slightly confused after reading the quickstart, do I need to place the code in a different IDE project or deploy the website to a hosting server? I've also tried hooking in the WSGI Middleware and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You don't need a different project, just run `flask --app WebManager_Main run`

Deploying to a hosting server will be useful if you want your web application to be available 24x7 to anyone.